# Printing elements not displayed

Tags: css

I have a few divs with text that have `display:none` set. While on the screen I have a functionality that changes it to `display:block` when I click other elements.

```
<div class="hiddenText" style="display:none">My hidden text</div>
```

I need to print the page and show all text. I added css file for print and specified display for hidden text

```
@media print {
   .hiddenText {
       display: block
   }
}
```

All styles for printed version of the document work great, except this. What is the best way to make it printable?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying the components are not showing up when you print them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inline styles have precedence over the rules specified elsewhere. To override inline styles you can use the `!important` keyword to force the rule.

Something like this will probably do the trick:

```
@media print {
   .hiddenText {
       display: block !important;
   }
}
```

Even though `!important` has nothing to do with CSS specificity, MDN has a section in [its article on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity) that discuss `!important`.

> When an !important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever
>   it is in the declaration list. Although, !important has nothing to do
>   with specificity.

Comment: You could also make the selector more specific so it overrides the current selector, something like: `body .hiddenText {display:block;}`. But this won't override inline-styles, just less specific CSS rules.

Comment: @Jasper That is a good point. I decided to not mention that in my answer, since OP was indeed dealing with inline styles.

Comment: OK, the answer above did not really solve the issue, but the explanation about inline styling prompted me to re-write my jQuery code to replace .show() .hide() with .addClass() .removeClass() which did fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@media print` try putting your print styles in something like this, `<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="print" HREF="foo.css">`

Comment: Yes, I actually put it in an external CSS file, I just used this here to show that I used PRINT media. Thanks.